# Office 365 outgoing mail server in Odoo

Tags: configuration, server, odoo, office365, outgoing-mail

I want to setup Office 365 account in Odoo. I am getting this error while sending mail from Odoo:

'Mail Delivery Failed', u"Mail delivery failed via SMTP server 'smtp.office365.com'.\nSMTPDataError: 550\n5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared a guide on how to integrate the Odoo ERP with Office 365 mail server ( https://ventor.tech/guides/how-to-configure-emails-to-work-with-office-365-and-odoo/ ). It has been verified by many customers already, and all screenshots are from latest Odoo (11 at the moment of writing) and the latest version of Office 365.

At a glance what should be done:

- Configure Outgoing mail Server in Office 365 as Relay Server
- Configure Catchall Email in Office 365
- Install Odoo module to inform users that they used the wrong email
- Configure Outgoing Mail Server in Odoo
- Configure Incoming Mail Server in Odoo
- Test Odoo ERP Emailing Setup